# chop and get values of string based on length PHP

Tags: php, regex

This question might look bit weird boot its keep blowing my mind since yesterday. I am getting a string from TCP/IP Packet which is something like this..

> "SiteName":"GPRSSignalStrength":"SelectedNetworkOperators":"GPRSReportingTimeOut":"SensorReportCount":"SensorReportUpdateStatus":"PacketLength":"SensorStatus":"SensorReportingInterval":"SensorType":"GSM
>   ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record
>   start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end"

My aim is to get the "SiteName" and all the values starting from "GSM ID" into another string. The main issue is the length of the packet may vary after the "Record start" block based on the "SensorReportCount" value. if "SensorReportCount" = 2 then we will have the same packet copied above if the "SensorReportCount" = 3 then we will have an extra report which would look like something

> "SiteName":"GPRSSignalStrength":"SelectedNetworkOperators":"GPRSReportingTimeOut":"SensorReportCount":"SensorReportUpdateStatus":"PacketLength":"SensorStatus":"SensorReportingInterval":"SensorType":"GSM
>   ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record
>   start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record
>   start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end".

how is that possible to save "Site Name" and all the other blocks after "GSM ID" in another string.?

Comment: what is your desire output?? How it will look like?

Comment: I want the desire output something like this 

`"SiteName":"GSM ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end"`

Comment: so you want to skip the other words....

Comment: Yes @FrayneKonok I want to get rid of the other words block for some other purposes.

Comment: do you need to do with regex or other???

Comment: I dont mind anything but i need to do that ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^(.*?):.*("GSM ID".*)\.
```

See the [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL1eK7/3)

Use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the submatches from the two capture groups. First capture group is for "SiteName" and the second is for everything after, and including, "GSM ID".

Comment: The string length vary based on the "SensorReportCount" element.. do you thing it would do the trick

Comment: Is the content in the "substitution" text area not what you expected? In the Regex demo..

Comment: You are welcome, if you haven't, take your time to see what the regex does in the "explanation" part of the Regex demo, just to see if it meets all your requirements.

Comment: what is the difference.?

Comment: Before, the capture group was capturing the final dot, but you dont need that, so I put it outside of the capture group, and there was a ":" inside the second capture group that was not needed for the match.

Comment: Thanks.. Really Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**String**

```
$text = '"SiteName":"GPRSSignalStrength":"SelectedNetworkOperators":"GPRSReportingTimeOut":"SensorReportCount":"SensorReportUpdateStatus":"PacketLength":"SensorStatus":"SensorReportingInterval":"SensorType":"GSM ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end"';
```

**PHP Regular Expresion**

```
$pattern = '[^(.+?:).+("GSM ID":.+)]';
preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $out);
```

For the pattern you need to use `+` not `*` cause, the `+` check for 1 or more that means if found.

**Result**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => "SiteName":"GPRSSignalStrength":"SelectedNetworkOperators":"GPRSReportingTimeOut":"SensorReportCount":"SensorReportUpdateStatus":"PacketLength":"SensorStatus":"SensorReportingInterval":"SensorType":"GSM ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => "SiteName":
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => "GSM ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end"
        )

)
```

The result will be same after concatenate the array index 1 and 2.

**PHP Explode**

```
$arr = explode(':"GSM ID"', $text);

echo '"SiteName":"GSM ID"'.$arr[1];
```

**Output:**

> "SiteName":"GSM ID":"Record start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end":"Record
>   start","S2, Main Kitchen
>   KE","000","3012,"RSSI","SensorOpticStatus","Record end"

Comment: If I would know the static length of the string I will do it but the main issue is the length of the string vary based on the "sensorReportCount", So I think We have to put it in loop or something.. but I dont know how.

Comment: so you need to give a worst case example.