# Remove static strings from dynamic string

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

This is the second half  of my task based on the string chopping (like this word) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861126/chop-and-get-values-of-string-based-on-length-php).

I am receiving a dynamic string of unknown length. I have done a little development, but the question is how can I remove all occurrences of the `RSSI` string?

I know it can be done using regex, but to be honest I have a very little knowledge of regex.

> Sensor Location,3,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023B6AD,S2 Main Kitchen KE,000,3012,RSSI,01,End of Sensor Report,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023B5BD,S2 Main Hall,741,3512,RSSI,01,End of Sensor Report,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023C6AD,S2 Lobby,579,3321,RSSI,01,End of Sensor Report

The expected output would be like:

> Sensor Location,3,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023B6AD,S2 Main Kitchen KE,000,3012,01,End of Sensor Report,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023B5BD,S2 Main Hall,741,3512,01,End of Sensor Report,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023C6AD,S2 Lobby,579,3321,01,End of Sensor Report

Comment: PHP function `str_replace` also did the trick.

Comment: you can use `str_replace(",RSSI", " ", ,$str)`

Comment: If you're going to keep asking questions about regexp, maybe you should try to learn about regexp. You can't really expect us to keep writing your program for you.

Comment: Welcome back @FrayneKonok. the issue is it would be the RSSI value not the "RSSI" string and the string would be dynamic. there could be multiple reports. Please do your regex trick

Comment: You mean you want to remove the field `01` that's after `RSSI`?

Comment: Why don't you explode the string into an array? Then find the field with `RSSI` and remove that field and the value field after it. Do that in a loop.

Comment: I know @Barmar. Thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: I want to remove the RSSI Field..

Comment: from your question how can we know which one is `RSSI block`????

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: After the block "Start of sensor Report" the 5th parameter would be RSSI.

Comment: so please update your question with your expected result.

Comment: @A_Singh I have edited the question for the output Thanks

Comment: Maybe try: `str_replace(",RSSI,", ",", $str)`

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that you are matching the full "needle" and not matching part of a string that is not your needle, match the commas on both sides of the needle and replace the match with a comma.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/efqi2))

```
$string = 'Sensor Location,3,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023B6AD,S2 Main Kitchen KE,000,3012,RSSI,01,End of Sensor Report,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023B5BD,S2 Main Hall,741,3512,RSSI,01,End of Sensor Report,Start of Sensor Report,000D6F000023C6AD,S2 Lobby,579,3321,RSSI,01,End of Sensor Report';

echo str_replace(',RSSI,', ',', $string);
```